# Do not rerender ReactNative flatlist items if data reordered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a `<FlatList data={items} numColumns={2} renderItem={_renderItem} />` and my items looks like `[{id:'a',imageUrl:'https://Foo.jpg'}, {id:'b',imageUrl:'https://Bar.jpg'}, {id:'c',imageUrl:'https://Love.jpg'}]`

This is how I render each items

```
const _renderItem = useCallback(
    ({item, index}) => {
      const media = item as Media;
      return (
        <MediasFeedItem
          media={media}
          onPress={() => _onMediaPress(media)}
          key={media.id}
          size={mediaSize}
          isSelected={!!selectedMedias.filter((m) => m.id === media.id).length}
        />
      );
    },
    [
      numColumns,
      selectedMedias,
      props.onPressMedia,
      props.onSelectionChange,
      props.selectable,
    ],
  );
```

If I clone my items `itemsClone = [...items]`, reorder itemsClone `itemsClone.sort(...)` and update my state `setState({items: itemsClone})` then the FlatList unmount/mount all my items element (`<MediasFeedItem />`) even tho' their content has not changed. Because they render an image it causes my list to blink each time I reorder the list. Any ideas how to improve this?

Comment: That's kind of inherent to `useCallback` rather than using normal React: [as per the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), "useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed" so if you're changing your list then yeah, you've just explicitly told React that you want it to redo everything. Can you explain why you need a memoized render funciton instance, instead of just rendering your list of `<MediasFeedItem>` in a normal component with a regular `render() { return this.state.feeditems.map(...) }`?

Comment: Actually the ``useCallback`` was here as experiment, I can omit it and do ``renderItem={ () =>  <MediasFeedItem /> }`` but I will still get this blinking issue...

Comment: remember: without code to back up that claim, no one has any reason to trust that to be true, so show your [mcve] for the other case(s) too, because it's entirely possibly you're _still_ using a code pattern that the React devs designed to allow you to _force_ React to update.